# A name or adjective for a shop/store/bar/exhibition which placed outside

Tags: word-request

I saw a picture where a guy sells carpet outside. I think he has a normal shop too but most of the his merchandises are seen without coming into the store. So I was just wondering how can we name these kind of places which are not inside a building. It could be a bar , a shop or even an art exhibition. What I mean here there is no wall. Everybody can see when they go by..I thought the word **open** but it is associated a lot with a meaning that a shop   open for business..

[image]

Comment: "Street vendor" is pretty common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective I’ve heard that would describe any of these examples is [**“open-air”**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/open-air).

- Open-air market
- Open-air seating (at a bar)
- Open-air patio (most patios are open-air, so this is a bit less common, but it could be used to distinguish from a *screened-in* patio or porch)

Another term is [**“al fresco”**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alfresco). This is a little bit fancier of a word that means essentially the same thing. It shows up most often in the phrase [“al fresco dining”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_fresco_dining) but can serve in other contexts.

If you want to go *less* fancy, the simple term **“outdoor”** is perfectly acceptable for all of these situations.

Answer (score 1):

You could call him a "street vendor", but that phrase/description has already been co-opted by people who sell items (usually food) and are not only who are physically located on a street, but also in a vehicle, with carts, or trucks.

In the picture you show, a '***sidewalk vendor***' is a more appropriate phrase.